# Error sending property object from .xhtml to bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have this .xhtml file. It's a data table page with three buttons (one for creating users, one for editing them and one for deleting them). Creating and deleting users are working but updating not. When I call the method `actionListener="#{usuariosBean.actualizarUsuario}"`, I get all parameters well but not the Id, I'm getting 0 instead of the real Id of the user.

I have tried to do it in different .xhtml and it work good so I think that the problem is about the .xhtml file but... I don't know. Could anybody help me? Thanks a lot!!!

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<body>

<ui:composition template="./../template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />

        <h:form>
            <p:commandButton update=":formCrear" icon="ui-icon-document"
                title="Crear Usuario" value="Crear Usuario"
                oncomplete="PF('usuarioDialogCrear').show();">
            </p:commandButton>
        </h:form>

        <h:form id="form">

            <p:dataTable var="usuario" value="#{usuariosBean.usuarios}"
                paginator="true" rows="10">

                <p:column headerText="Id">
                    <h:outputText value="#{usuario.id}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Nombre de Usuario">
                    <h:outputText value="#{usuario.nombreDeUsuario}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Contraseña">
                    <h:outputText value="#{usuario.contrasenya}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Rol">
                    <h:outputText value="#{usuario.rol}" />
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="" style="text-align:center; width:4%">
                    <p:commandButton update=":form:usuarioActualizar" id="Actualizar"
                        icon="ui-icon-pencil" title="Actualizar"
                        oncomplete="PF('usuarioDialogActualizar').show();">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{usuario}"
                            target="#{usuariosBean.usuarioSeleccionado}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="" style="text-align:center; width:4%">
                    <p:commandButton update=":form:usuarioEliminar" id="Eliminar"
                        icon="ui-icon-close" title="Eliminar"
                        oncomplete="PF('confirmacion').show();">
                        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{usuario}"
                            target="#{usuariosBean.usuarioSeleccionado}" />
                    </p:commandButton>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>

            <p:dialog header="Actualizar Usuario"
                widgetVar="usuarioDialogActualizar" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
                hideEffect="explode" resizable="false" width="400">
                <p:outputPanel id="usuarioActualizar" style="text-align:center;"
                    layout="block">

                    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputText value="Id " />
                        <p:inputText
                            value="#{usuariosBean.usuarioSeleccionado.id}"
                            style="font-weight:bold" size="37" />
                        <h:outputText value="Usuario: " />
                        <p:inputText
                            value="#{usuariosBean.usuarioSeleccionado.nombreDeUsuario}"
                            style="font-weight:bold" size="37" />
                        <h:outputText value="Contraseña: " />
                        <p:inputText
                            value="#{usuariosBean.usuarioSeleccionado.contrasenya}"
                            style="font-weight:bold" size="37" />
                        <h:outputText value="Rol " />
                        <p:inputText value="#{usuariosBean.usuarioSeleccionado.rol}"
                            style="font-weight:bold" size="37" />
                    </p:panelGrid>

                </p:outputPanel>

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton update=":form, :msgs" id="btnActualizarAceptar"
                        icon="ui-icon-disk" title="Guardar Usuario"
                        value="Actualizar Usuario"
                        actionListener="#{usuariosBean.actualizarUsuario}"
                        oncomplete="PF('usuarioDialogActualizar').hide()">
                    </p:commandButton>

                    <p:commandButton id="btnActualizarCancelar" icon="ui-icon-close"
                        title="Cancelar" value="Cancelar" type="button"
                        onclick="PF('usuarioDialogActualizar').hide()">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </f:facet>
            </p:dialog>

            <p:confirmDialog
                message="¿Está seguro que desea eliminar el usuario?"
                showEffect="bounce" hideEffect="explode" header="Eliminar Usuario"
                severity="alert" widgetVar="confirmacion">
                <p:outputPanel id="usuarioEliminar" style="text-align:center;"
                    layout="block">
                    <h:inputHidden value="#{usuariosBean.usuarioSeleccionado.id}" />
                </p:outputPanel>

                <p:commandButton id="confirmarDialogo" value="Aceptar"
                    icon="ui-icon-check" update=":form, :msgs"
                    oncomplete="PF('confirmacion').hide()"
                    actionListener="#{usuariosBean.eliminarUsuario}" />

                <p:commandButton id="cancelarDialogo" icon="ui-icon-close"
                    title="Cancelar" value="Cancelar"
                    oncomplete="PF('confirmacion').hide()">
                </p:commandButton>
            </p:confirmDialog>
        </h:form>

        <h:form id="formCrear">
            <p:dialog header="Crear Usuario" widgetVar="usuarioDialogCrear"
                modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode"
                resizable="false" width="400">

                <p:outputPanel id="usuarioCrear" style="text-align:center;"
                    layout="block">

                    <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputText value="Usuario: " />
                        <p:inputText value="#{usuariosBean.nombreDeUsuario}"
                            required="true" size="37" />
                        <h:outputText value="Contraseña: " />
                        <p:inputText value="#{usuariosBean.contrasenya}" required="true"
                            size="37" />
                        <h:outputText value="Rol " />
                        <p:inputText value="#{usuariosBean.rol}" required="true"
                            size="37" />
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </p:outputPanel>

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton update=":form, :msgs" id="btnCrearAceptar"
                        icon="ui-icon-disk" title="Guardar Usuario"
                        value="Guardar Usuario" action="#{usuariosBean.guardarUsuario}"
                        oncomplete="PF('usuarioDialogCrear').hide()">
                    </p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton id="btnCrearCancelar" icon="ui-icon-close"
                        title="Cancelar" value="Cancelar"
                        oncomplete="PF('usuarioDialogCrear').hide()">
                    </p:commandButton>
                </f:facet>

            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>


    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Best practice is to put the forms inside the dialogs. I am in doubt about where the confirmdialog would go then, but I think it should be inside the main form. You dont have a form in the template right?

Comment: I've just done what primefaes showcase says... I don't have a form in the template. Anyway I'll try and I tell you! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a proper setter for `id` property in your `Usuario` class? Please note that tipically and generally speaking in JEE applications an `id` is a read-only property likely auto-assigned when the entity is persisted. In this scenario it wouldn't make sense update this property.

Comment: I don't want to update the id, I only want to send it to the bean. With de delete method it works fine, but not with the update I don't know why... I have implemented it by another way, that's not what I wanted to do but at this moment it will be ok... I will research this question when I have more "free" time and I tell you all!